# How to invoke a function when a variable is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, events

I need to call 'readapi' asynchronous function whenever 'command' variable receives a new value.

```
setInterval( function loop() {
    rec.stop();
    rec.start().pipe(request.post({
      'url'     : 'https://etc..lang=en-us&output=json',
      'headers' : {
        'Content-Type'  : 'audio/wav'
      }
    }, exports.parseResult));
     },4000);
    })

exports.parseResult = function (err, resp, body) {
  try {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Parsing body: " + body);
    if ((body.entities) && typeof body.entities.local_search_query !== 'undefined')
    query = body.entities.local_search_query[0].value;
    console.log('query:' + query);
    readapi.gifs(query).then(function (res){
      io.emit("chat", res)
    }, query);


  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Try catch error: " + e);
  }
}

}
```

Is there a better way to refactor this working code?

Comment: "But if a add a second check to prevent the TypeError, it never actually goes inside the if() statement." Because `body.entities` is not defined. Where are `body` and `body.entities` defined?

Comment: @rveerd I added the missing code to the question. It's exported from a post.

Comment: they are defined when I speak to the computer microphone. The API post call returns a JSON object, but no matter what I do, I can't get inside the if statement. The problem is I need to know if its undefined before command = body.entities.local_search_query.value; or it will typeError crash.

Comment: Check the value of `body` when you enter your `parseResults` function and before your `if` statement. Use `console.log` or a debugger. What is the result? Does it have an `entities` field?

Comment: @rveerd body is {
  "_text" : "",
  "entities" : { }
}

Comment: That looks like a JSON string, *not* a JavaScript object. Use `JSON.parse(body)` to convert it to a JavaScript object.

Comment: @rveerd Thanks. It's partially working now. I updated my question. Please post an answer and I'll be happy to accept.